# combine 2 awk loops in one bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have this script that i built and it works ok, but i would like to combine the 2 awks in one so i that i have all info on 1 line, is this possible to do?

```
for i in `cat domains` ; do
  IFS='=' read -a array <<< "$i"
  CC=`echo "${array[0]}"`

  awk  -v c=$CC '{a[substr($4,2,17)]++}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i], c}}' "${array[1]}".access_log | sort
  awk  -v c=$CC '{if ($0 ~ /html/) b[substr($4,2,17)]++}END{for(j in b){print j, b[j], c}}' "${array[1]}".access_log | sort

  exit
done
```

snippet from domains:

```
af=www.google.com.af
al=www.google.al
ao=www.google.co.ao
ar=www.google.com.ar
au=www.google.com.au
```

Eg:
given af=www.google.com.af
running against www.google.com.af.access_log

```
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:35:18 +0200] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:35:18 +0200] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:36:18 +0200] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:36:18 +0200] "GET /main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:36:18 +0200] "GET /main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:37:18 +0200] "GET /main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:37:18 +0200] "GET /main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
- - - [21/Jul/2014:14:37:18 +0200] "GET /main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "MobileSafari/9537.53 CFNetwork/672.1.15 Darwin/14.0.0" 556
```

should return

```
21/Jul/2014:14:35 total: 2 html: 0
21/Jul/2014:14:36 total: 3 html: 2
21/Jul/2014:14:37 total: 3 html: 3
```

Comment: Please show a sample of `domains`.

Comment: It would be useful to edit your answer to show us a sample of `domains`.

Comment: If we have some data from `domains` and what result you like to have, we may do all in one `awk`, remove all `for`,`IFS` etc.

Comment: OK, so you've posted the sample input, that's a good start. Now post the expected output given that input.

Comment: With your code and domain file, this gives `awk: fatal: cannot open file 'www.google.com.af.access_log' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Your sample input only has 1 field but your scripts operate on field 4 and expect to find `html` on at least some lines so presumably that is not what your input actually looks like, please correct it. Also, post the expected output you want from your sample input.

Comment: @Ed Morton - that's because the access log is an apache log with many fields $4 contains the date ( the script does a count on similar lines on a minute granularity )

Comment: Whatever it is - just post a small representative sample of it and the expected output. That's all were asking for to be able to start helping you.

Comment: would be to have one awk to output something like date:total:htmlcount:countrycode

Comment: It may be that you don't understand what we are asking for (sample input and expected output) but it seems far more likely that you do understand and are simply unwilling to put the small amount of effort into providing it so you're unlikely to get an answer and if you do it's unlikely to be the best solution to your problem (hint - any time you write a shell loop just to parse text files you almost certainly have the wrong approach).

Comment: i get it now sry: here's what the outcome should be http://pastebin.com/VfkNWbFq

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop to iterate over the file: `IFS='=' read -a array; do ...; done < domains`

Comment: I copied your pastebin info into your question where it's easiest for us to see it in context with all of your other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your bash and merge your two awks with:

```
while IFS== read cc domain; do
    awk -v c="$CC" 'BEGIN { OFS = ":" } { d = substr($4,2,17); ++a[d] } /html/ { ++b[d] } END { for (i in a) print i, a[i], b[i] ? b[i] : "0", c }' "$domain".access_log | sort
done < domains
```

To keep the order without using `sort`:

```
while IFS== read cc domain; do
    awk -v cc="$CC" 'BEGIN { OFS = ":" } { i = substr($4,2,17) } !a[i]++ { d[++j] = i } /html/ { ++b[i] } END { for (j = 1; j in d; ++j) { i = d[j]; print i, a[i], b[i] ? b[i] : "0", cc } }' "$domain".access_log
done < domains
```

Comment: it's perfect! :) any idea why awk doesn't keep the default order of the lines?

Comment: @punked It depends on the implementation. Sometimes an associative array is not sorted for the sake of faster processing. You can use another indexed array to store the keys in order.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the implementation. awk arrays are stored as hash tables and the `in` operator access them in the order in which they are are stored. You can modify that behavior in GNU awk using `PROCINFO[sorted_in]`, see the man page, but that just defines sorting order by default, there is no option to access them in the order in which they were read unless you provide a function to provide that order.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need something like this (using GNU awk for ENDFILE and delete array):

```
awk '
NR==FNR { ARGV[ARGC++] = $2 ".access_log"; next }
{
    time = substr($4,2,17)
    totCount[time]++
    if (/html/)
        htmlCount[time]++
}
ENDFILE {
    for (time in totCount) {
        print time, "total:", totCount[time], "html:", htmlCount[time]+0, FILENAME
    }
    delete totCount
    delete htmlCount
}
' FS="=" domains FS=" "
```

No surrounding shell loop necessary. If you want the order of the timestamps in your output to match the order in your input just tweak it keep track of the order:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { ARGV[ARGC++] = $2 ".access_log"; next }
{
    time = substr($4,2,17)
    totCount[time]++
    if (/html/)
        htmlCount[time]++
    if (!seen[time]++)
        times[++numTimes] = time
}
ENDFILE {
    for (i=1; i <= numTimes; i++) {
        time = times[i]
        print time, "total:", totCount[time], "html:", htmlCount[time]+0, FILENAME
    }
    delete totCount
    delete htmlCount
    delete times
    delete seen
    numTimes = 0
}
' FS="=" domains FS=" "
21/Jul/2014:14:35 total: 2 html: 0 www.google.com.af.access_log
21/Jul/2014:14:36 total: 3 html: 2 www.google.com.af.access_log
21/Jul/2014:14:37 total: 3 html: 3 www.google.com.af.access_log
21/Jul/2014:14:35 total: 2 html: 0 www.google.al.access_log
21/Jul/2014:14:36 total: 3 html: 2 www.google.al.access_log
21/Jul/2014:14:37 total: 3 html: 3 www.google.al.access_log
```

The above was using a domains file with just those 2 domains in it and with both ".log" files identical to the sample you posted.